# Capturar dados de sessão com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tentando fazer um sisteminha em que no meu banco de dados de usuário tem 4 campos: `usuario_id`, `usuario_nome`, `usuario_senha` e `usuario_empresa_id`.

Eu preciso capturar o dado de `usuario_empresa_id` (que recebe o `id` da tabela `empresa` na hora que um usuário faz um cadastro de empresa junto com o login dele) e colocar dentro do campo `empresa_id` da tabela `deposito`, porém dentro, quando eu tento recuperar o `usuario_empresa_id` que está na *session*, ele sempre retorna `0`. Alguém conseguiria me explicar o motivo?

Segue o código:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);

$query = ("SELECT usuario_id, usuario_nome FROM usuarios 
WHERE usuario_nome = '$usuario' AND usuario_senha = '$senha'");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$QR = ("SELECT usuario_empresa_id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_nome = '$usuario' AND usuario_senha = '$senha'");
$result_qr = mysqli_query($conn, $QR);
$idempresa = mysqli_num_rows($result_qr);

if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: painel.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

if ($_SESSION['usuario']){
    $_SESSION['idempresa'] = $idempresa;
}
?>
```

segue o código da inserção na tabela deposito

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conexao.php");


$empresa = $_SESSION['idempresa'];


$deposito = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['deposito']);

$result_deposito = "INSERT INTO depositos(
'deposito_nome', 
'deposito_empresa_id') 
 VALUES( 
'$deposito',
'$empresa'
)";
$resultado_deposito = mysqli_query($conn, $result_deposito);

?>
```

Comment: Já deu um var_dump na variável `$idempresa`?

Comment: sim, não aponta nada

Comment: Acho que vc poderia explicar melhor. No código não mostra nada relacionado à tabela "deposito" citada, e em nenhum momento vc está usando `usuario_empresa_id` do SELECT da query `$QR`. A única coisa que vejo vc fazer é contar rows com `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: a inserção na tabela deposito eu tento fazer em outro arquivo  chamando a  $_SESSION['idempresa']. você saberia me dizer como eu faço o uso da query então?

Comment: Não entendi muito sua pergunta. Você quer pegar o valor de $idempresa e colocar dentro de uma sessão para chamar em outro local?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você encerra o script antes de adicionar o $idempresa na sessão.

Pega esse código

```
$_SESSION['idempresa'] = $idempresa;
```

e coloca dentro do

```
if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['idempresa'] = $idempresa;
```

Edit:

Na linha:

```
$idempresa = mysqli_num_rows($result_qr);
```

voce esta pegando a quantidade de linhas `mysqli_num_rows` e não o valor do registro. Substitua por `mysqli_query`

Edit 2:

Para ver o dados obtidos do usuário use o var_dump na variável `$db_user`

```
$result_qr = mysqli_query($conn, $QR);
$db_user = $result_qr->fetch_assoc();

if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['idempresa'] = $db_user['usuario_empresa_id'];
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: painel.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Edit 3:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);

$query = ("SELECT usuario_id, usuario_nome, usuario_empresa_id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_nome = '$usuario' AND usuario_senha = '$senha'");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$usuario = $result->fetch_assoc();

if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['idempresa'] = $usuario['usuario_empresa_id'];
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario['usuario_nome'];
    header('Location: painel.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: removi o exit(); do if e agora dando um echo na variavel $empresa = $_SESSION['idempresa']; ele da resultado como 1, mesmo o usuario_empresa_id não sendo 1. Você sabe como resolver?

Comment: Qual valor da variável $row?

Comment: é 1, mas seu eu troco por > 0 por exemplo ele não faz o login do meu sistema, não sei o motivo... Você saberia alguma forma de eu pegar o usuario_empresa_id da session de outra forma?

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na resposta, vc testou dessa maneira?

Comment: sim, continua retornando 1

Comment: Editei novamente a resposta, parece que o erro esta na variavel idempresa

Comment: você sabe qual  eu devo usar então? o mysqli_fetch_array e mysqli_fetch_assoc retornam esse erro: Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: Posta o var_dump da variavel $result_qr, lá deve ter o valor que você precisa, ou você pode atribuir direto na variável $idempresa = $result_qr['idempresa'], ou algo do tipo.

Comment: não sei como exibir o valor desse var_dump, pois esse código ta no arquivo login.php que assim que é verificado o login e a senha redireciona pro painel.php, ele não fica ali pra dar pra ver o var_dump, e se eu entro direto nessa login.php ele não vai ta em uma session. a outra orma não funcionou, da uma pagina em branco

Comment: coloca antes do `if($row == 1) {` o `var_dump($result_qr);exit();`

Comment: o resultado é: object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: deu certo, amigo. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você tentou:

// usuario_empresa_id as vezes tem que tá escrito igual no banco.

```
$idempresa = $result_qr['usuario_empresa_id'];
$_SESSION['idempresa'] = $idempresa;
```

Aí basta troccar.

```
if($idempresa == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: painel.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```